# помогите найти ошибку mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

Код где ошибка:

```
<?php
require 'vyzdb.php';
$univer_info=mysql_query("SELECT * FORM vuz");
$univer = mysql_fetch_array($univer_info);
$id=$univer['id'];
$name=$univer['univer_name'];
$city=$univer['univer_city'];
$street=$univer['univer_street'];
$contact=$univer['univer_contact'];
$web=$univer['univer_web'];
 "<h2>Название:$name.<br>Адрес:$city, $street.<br>Телефон: $contact.<br>Web:$web.";
?>
```

да я обращался с такой же ошибкой, но прикол в том, что там теперь все работает, причем в 3 файлах и без каких либо ошибок, а здесь ошибка! Хотя код вроде правильно написан.
 при нужной мне перестройки все равно это ошибка(тот вариант в инете, типа ошибка сразу исчезнет)
вот нужный код

```
$univer_info=mysql_query("SELECT * FORM vuz");
while ($univer = mysql_fetch_array($univer_info)){
    $id=$univer['id'];
$name=$univer['univer_name'];
$city=$univer['univer_city'];
$street=$univer['univer_street'];
$contact=$univer['univer_contact'];
$web=$univer['univer_web'];
    "<h2>Название:$name.<br>Адрес:$city, $street.<br>Телефон: $contact.<br>Web:$web.";
}
```

Он должен подключиться к бд и из каждой строки вынести информацию на страницу.
Но выводит только это:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in Z:\home\server.ru\www\title.php on line 6